# Internet very slow when connected to router wifi

Tags: wireless

My laptop connection speed to internet is so slow when it's connected to router wifi. But when connected via ethernet wire everything is normal. Also when it is connected to mobile phone hotspot or when I use it in Windows OS, it works perfectly.

Please help me, thanks.

**Update**

It seems that the source problem is older routers don't support 802.11n protocol.

Comment: you need to expand your question with details about what specifically you have tried to avoid proposed solutions which you have already tried unsuccessfully. Please read [ask] then [edit] accordingly.

Comment: What's your MTU? `ip link show` will tell you, as will ` ip l | grep $(ip r | awk '/default/ {print $5}' ) | awk '{print $2, $4, $5}'`. For WiFi, it should be 1492, not the 1500 used for wired Ethernet

Comment: @waltinator it shows wlp1s0: mtu 1500 while I am using WiFi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by disabling 802.11n.

open file `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` with text editor and add following text

`options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`

Then reboot your computer.