# Wifi very slow with some sources (modem vs android hotspot)

Tags: networking, wireless, dns

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 for 1 year now and recently stumbled on wifi issues.

When connected to my router the internet connection is very slow and often interrupted. I don't have this problem at all when connected to my android smartphone.

When I ping google (router connection) which usually works :

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
De 192.168.1.54 icmp_seq=1 Host unreachable
De 192.168.1.54 icmp_seq=2 Hôte de destination injoignable
De 192.168.1.54 icmp_seq=3 Hôte de destination injoignable
```

I tried this solution with no sucess
[Internet very slow when connected to router wifi](https://askubuntu.com/q/1373716/1668196)

Output from `sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network                 
       description: Interface réseau sans fil
       produit: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       fabricant: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:07:00.0
       nom logique: wlp7s0
       version: 01
       numéro de série: //
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration : broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.43.6 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       ressources : irq:18 mémoire:b7300000-b7307fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       produit: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabricant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:08:00.0
       nom logique: enp8s0
       version: 0c
       numéro de série: //
       capacité: 1Gbit/s
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration : autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.048.00-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       ressources : irq:48 portE/S:4000(taille=256) mémoire:b7200000-b7200fff mémoire:b7000000-b7003fff
```

I have also switched on/off all possibilities with 2.4GHz and 5GHz on my router, this does not help.

Comment: There is nothing that can be done on software level. It can be a bad contact with antennas, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Pilot6. I can't quite understand why it isn't related to software. In fact : Via hotspot it is functionning today, it was previously functionning with strictly the same router and with the router sometimes it works for 5 minutes and then drops.

Comment: Does `iwconfig` show power management enabled?  That can cause issues.  It could also be related to the encryption used on wifi as some drivers don't like TKIP

Comment: ```wlp7s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID://
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: //
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off```
Power management is off

Comment: Removing TKIP encryption on the router did not help either unfortunately.

One piece of information I missed : sometimes a DNS type error shows up when the connection crashes.